# How to transform a Gremlin GraphSON in tree format to custom JSON tree format in CosmosDB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, graph-databases, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I have the following Gremlin queries that ran successfully in CosmosDB:

```
g.addV('person').property(id, 'grand_father').property('name', 'Grand Father')
g.addV('person').property(id, 'father').property('name', 'Father')
g.addV('person').property(id, 'child').property('name', 'Child')
g.V('grand_father').addE('father_of').to(V('father'))
g.V('father').addE('father_of').to(V('child'))
```

I ran the query `g.V('grand_father').repeat(out()).emit().tree()` which generates the following output:

```
[
  {
    "grand_father": {
      "key": {
        "id": "grand_father",
        "label": "person",
        "type": "vertex",
        "properties": {
          "name": [
            {
              "id": "2b687c65-6490-4846-a5ef-1b7d67e51916",
              "value": "Grand Father"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "value": {
        "father": {
          "key": {
            "id": "father",
            "label": "person",
            "type": "vertex",
            "properties": {
              "name": [
                {
                  "id": "c1f75463-8aa5-4c15-854d-88be0ec9cdc9",
                  "value": "Father"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "value": {
            "child": {
              "key": {
                "id": "child",
                "label": "person",
                "type": "vertex",
                "properties": {
                  "name": [
                    {
                      "id": "d74d6286-5fa9-4b90-9619-1f173d5da53e",
                      "value": "Child"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              "value": {}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I want to transform the above GraphSON tree again to generate a custom hierarchical tree of the following format.

```
{
   "person":{
      "name":"Grand Father"
   },
   "children":[
      {
         "person":{
            "name":"Father"
         },
         "children":[
            {
               "person":{
                  "name":"Child"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

What changes that I need to make to `g.V('grand_father').repeat(out()).emit().tree()` to achieve the result?

Comment: Hi, any chance you managed to achieve that? I am looking to do the same and I ended up adding a post script with tons of regexp to do it...

Answer (score 2):

I think that the following gets pretty close to what you're asking:

```
gremlin> g.V('grand_father').
......1>   repeat(out()).
......2>     emit().
......3>   tree().
......4>     by(group().
......5>          by(label).
......6>          by(valueMap('name').by(unfold())).
......7>        unfold().unfold())
==>[person={name=Grand Father}:[person={name=Father}:[person={name=Child}:[]]]]
```

Note that `tree()` takes a `by()` modulator which applies the anonymous traversal given to it as an argument to each item of the tree. I didn't capture the "children" leaf in your JSON output, but perhaps this gets you close enough to your target without introducing more complexity. Note that CosmosDB might not yet support the `valueMap('name').by(unfold())` trick in which case you can remove the `by(unfold())` and be left with `List` wrapping the value, replace it with `project('name').by('name')`, or replace it with the "old" way of unfolding a `valueMap()` shown next:

```
gremlin> g.V('grand_father').
......1>   repeat(out()).
......2>     emit().
......3>   tree().
......4>     by(group().
......5>          by(label).
......6>          by(valueMap('name').
......7>             unfold().
......8>             group().
......9>               by(select(keys)).
.....10>               by(select(values).unfold())).
.....11>        unfold().unfold())
==>[person={name=Grand Father}:[person={name=Father}:[person={name=Child}:[]]]]
```

Comment: For the second query, I get the error message: ```ExceptionType : GraphAssertException\nExceptionMessage :\r\n\tcompositeObjField != null```

Comment: For the first query, I get the error message: ```Unsupported Error: Gremlin op does not support by(traversal)\n```

Comment: sorry....my examples run against the reference graph implementation for TinkerPop which is meant to be the standard for demonstrating expected Gremlin semantics, so theoretically, every TinkerPop-enabled graph should have the same behavior as it. unfortunately, every so often CosmosDB doesn't quite match the expected semantics. i expected the first query to fail as that syntax i mentioned is new to 3.4.x and I figured that CosmosDB didn't support that yet. i'm less sure about why the second query is failing just this moment.

Comment: I solved this problem with SQL and LINQ before by selecting all the nodes, and iterating through them in a ```for``` loop to generate the tree. I tried to solve this problem an year ago with ```neo4j``` but could not because they did not have a ```tree()``` function out of the box. I'm leaning towards a solution of generate a tree with ```g.V('grand_father').repeat(out()).emit().tree()```, string parse it and generate the custom tree that I need. That is double processing (1) at the Gremlin server to generate the firs tree (2) at the API level again to generate the custom tree.

Comment: Do you recommend a book or blog that describe how a function like ```tree()``` or Gremling **step** works?

Comment: that may be your're only approach. i'd only recommend that you use `by()` as i did to pair down your results a bit to just the data you need to save on serialization costs and network payload size. there really is no other documentation for `tree()` besides there Reference Documentation http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#tree-step and the Practical Gremlin book: http://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html There really isn't much to it beyond what I've demonstrated with it. Pretty simple step.